# Why is my text align not correctly aligned?

Tags: html, css

I've been searching this question on Stack Overflow.  I've tried but my text align doesn't work, it's just null.  tried to use display: block, width: 100% and whatever I could find, but I unfortunately got no luck. I got no error messages whatsoever. as of right now, I have no clue on what is causing it

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap');
/*bg*/
img.bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 104px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
          z-index: -1;
}

h1{
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #690000;
    font-size: 112px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
        text-align: center;
            display: block;
            width:100%;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>e</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: orange;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="center">Denied</h1>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove that width from the body (also the height). Both are useless

Comment: You've got two `<!DOCTYPE html>` declarations, along with two `<html>` tags. Both of these are invalid HTML. It's a wonder anything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pasted your `html` code twice in your answer and this is making a mess to understand your code. Although your question is quite simple and I have answered in as simplest way as I can.

You should set `text-align` property to a parent `div or span` instead of direct `HTML tag`.

And while giving animation please don't give it a width if you want you items to be at center, for clarity see the attached **snippet**

```css
.denied{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
}
body {
        background-color: red;
        animation-name: example;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-direction: alternate;
      }

      @keyframes example {
        from {
          background-color: red;
        }
        to {
          background-color: orange;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="denied">
<h1>Denied</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**So,** if you are learning web development then it's ok to make mistakes.

The thing you were doing wrong is just the whole format of the code

```
body,html,head
```

These are just used 1 time and you just used them as `divs`

What you should have done was like this -

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>e</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <style>
      body {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        animation-name: example;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-direction: alternate;
      }

      @keyframes example {
        from {
          background-color: red;
        }
        to {
          background-color: orange;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 class="center">Denied</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap");
/*bg*/
img.bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 104px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #690000;
  font-size: 112px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Your syntax of writing the code was very wrong

and I think you would have wanted the heading `h1` inside the `div` like this-

```
<div>
  <h1 class="center">Denied</h1>
</div>
```

and not leaving the div empty for no reason at all

**After all this** the main thing due to which you were not able to center it through `text-align: center;` was, you just had to take width as `100vw` and not `100%`

```
`width: 100vw;`
```

means you are taking the width of the element in respect of the screen means-

if you are viewing your website through a desktop whose width = 600px then your `<h1 class="center">Denied</h1>` width will be equal to the width of the screen which is `600px`

**At Last** I would suggest you see the syntax of the `html` and `css` properly

**A Quick Tip -** if you are using VSCode for writing code you can just write `!` on an empty HTML file and it will automatically write the `HTML` template with `head, body,HTML and all that stuff.